# Fazer print de resultado de form fora da id usando linguagem JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um pequeno form que fornece um resultado em função da entrada de dois valores via form. Só que quero que a impressão do resultado seja feito fora do form do resultado. Já tentei de tudo e não consigo. Ocorrem 3 possibilidades:

1. O resultado aparece: `[object][Object]`: o que ocorreu algumas poucas vezes quando altero a programação;
2. Faz a leitura do "else" do "terceiro if" e aí aparece a frase: Por favor refaça a sua consulta. Isso ocorre quando tenho a sentença: - `var resultado = $("#valor3").val();` - (o mais comum; ele não 'calcula' e entende que o valor é nulo);
3. 'undefined' que ocorre quando tenho essa expressão: `var resultado = $("#resultado").val();`

Deixo o código para análise, sou bastante principiante em JavaScript:

CÓDIGO (arquivo em .html) - Deixo na forma 'undefined'

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<style type="text/css">
 .btn { }
 .n1 { }
 .n2 { }
 .n3 { }
</style>    
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function somarValores(){    
        var s1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;    
        var valor1 = convToFloat(s1) * 0.50;    
        var s2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;    
        var valor2 = convToFloat(s2) * 12;    
        var valor3 = valor1 + valor2;    
   document.getElementbyClassName(resultado).value = valor3;            
   }    

    function convToFloat(temp) {    
        var value;    

        if (temp.indexOf(',') == -1) {    
            temp = temp.replace(",", ".");    
        }    
        return parseFloat(temp); 
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".btn").click(function(){

         var volume = $("#valor1").val();

     if(volume != 0){

      $("#n1").html("<font color='#828282' face='arial'><b>RELAT&Oacute;RIO</font><br><br>Volume do ambiente: <font color='blue'>" + volume + " m&sup3;</b></font>");

           }else{   

      $("#n1").html("<font color='#828282' face='arial'><b>RELAT&Oacute;RIO</font><br><br>Campo <i>Volume</i> n&atilde;o preenchido!</b>");

         }

         var pessoa = $("#valor2").val();

     if(pessoa != 0){

      $("#n2").html("<b>N&uacute;mero de pessoas: <font color='blue'>" + pessoa + "</b></font>");

           }else{   

      $("#n2").html("<b>Campo <i>N&uacute;mero de Pessoas</i> n&atilde;o preenchido!</b>");

         }

     var resultado = $("#resultado").val(); 

          if(resultado != 0){ 

           $("#n3").html("<b>N&uacute;mero de pessoas: <font color='blue'>" + resultado + "</b></font>");      

           }else{   

      $("#n3").html("<b>Por favor, refa&ccedil;a sua consulta!</b>");          

   }
       return false;

     })

    })


  </script>
</head>

<body>

 <br>

  <table width="30%" border="0">
    <tr>
     <td width="30%" align="center" valign="center" bgcolor="#EEEEE0">
      <font color="#8B8B83" face="arial"><b> - Estimativa de Carga T&eacute;rmica - </b></font>
        </td></tr></table><br>

 <table width="30%"><tr><td width="30%">
 <form method="post" action""><fieldset><legend></legend>
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
     <td width="50%" align="right" valign="center">
      <b>Volume (&nbsp;m&sup3;): </b>
        </td>

     <td width="50%" align="center" valign="center">
       <input type="text" name="volume" id="valor1" size="5"/></td></tr>

      <tr>
       <td width="50%" align="right" valign="center">
         <b>N&#186; de Pessoas: </b>
        </td>

       <td width="50%" align="center" valign="center">
      <input type="text" name="pessoa" id="valor2" size="5"/></td></tr>


      <tr>
       <td width="50%" align="center" valign="center">
         <br><br>
        </td>

       <td width="50%" align="center" valign="center">
           <input type="text" name="resultado" id="valor3" hidden/>
           <input type="submit" value="Calcular Carga T&eacute;rmica" class="btn"/>
        </td></tr></table></fieldset>



 <br>
<dd><div id="n1"><p></p></div><br>
<div id="n2"><p></p></div><br>
<div id="n3"><p></p></div></dd>


</form>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oi, Fabiano, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. A formatação aqui no site é com Markdown, tem um [guia rápido aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). O legal é tentar sempre reduzir o código ao máximo até deixar somente a parte que demonstra seu problema. É uma boa técnica pois te ajuda a encontrar o problema sozinho também, e tem um outro guia pra isso:  [*Como fazer um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: O seu HTML e o seu script não combinam bem nos nomes. No javascript faz referência a elementos que não encontro no HTML e tem alguns erros como `document.getElementbyClassName(resultado)` onde essa variável não existe. Talvez faltem aspas aí? Pode explicar o que quer fazer? Assim podemos usar o HTML e melhorar o javascript.

Comment: E não vejo também onde está a chamar a função `somarValores()`

Comment: Olá Sérgio, tentei com aspas e não funcionou. Bom o que eu quero: Entrada de dados (2 ou mais inputs) e uma saída impressa FORA da caixa do form. Consigo fazer com a impressão do resultado no form, através do 'readonly' mas quero que fique fora. Acredito que não seja difícil, mas sou principiante no javascript. É isso!

Comment: E quer somar os campos somente? quer enviar a form para o servidor ou só mostrar no ecrâ?

Comment: Só mostrar mesmo.

Comment: @Fabiano estou sem tempo agora mas se ninguem responder daqui a pouco já ajudo. Pode clarificar a matemática que quer fazer? quer usar a função `somarValores` ou somente "somar" os valores?

Comment: Ok. O cálculo (são várias planilhas em páginas diferentes, mas a ideia é a mesma) é o seguinte:

Comment: Ok. O cálculo (são várias planilhas em páginas diferentes, mas a ideia é a mesma) é o seguinte: Valor1 = input1 x N1; Valor2 = input2 x N2; Resultado (a imprimir) = Valor1 + Valor2; sendo que N1  N2 são números pré-definidos... Como disse, input1 e input2 são inseridos via campo form type text e o resultado quero impressão fora. Se puder ajudar, seria de grande contribuição para a montagem do meu site. Ah, quanto a função, qualquer uma, desde que resolva meu problema. Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o JavaScript que precisa é este:

```
function somarValores() {
    var s1 = document.getElementById("valor1").value;
    var valor1 = convToFloat(s1) * 0.50;
    var s2 = document.getElementById("valor2").value;
    var valor2 = convToFloat(s2) * 12;
    return [valor1, valor2];
}

function convToFloat(temp) {
    if (temp.indexOf(',') == -1) temp = temp.replace(",", ".");
    return parseFloat(temp);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // impedir a form de ser enviada para o servidor
        var input = somarValores(); // calcular os valores
        $('#n1 span').text(input[0]);
        $('#n2 span').text(input[1]);
        $('#n3 span').text(input[0] + input[1]);
    });
})
```

O HTML do resultado sugiro assim:

```
<div class="resultado">
     <h2>RELAT&Oacute;RIO</h2>
    <div id="n1">Volume do ambiente: <span></span> m&sup3;</div>
    <div id="n2">Número de pessoas: <span></span></div>
    <div id="n3">Total: <span></span></div>
</div>
```

Aí para formatar o layout/design deve usar CSS e não no HTML.

Por exemplo:

```
.resultado {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.resultado span {
    color: blue;
}
```

A função somar valores vai buscar o input e retorna os dois valores calculados numa array. Assim só precisa somar.

O seu HTML está desnecessáriamente complexo. Acho que dava para limpar muito aí. Não sei bem porque tem uma `<form>` se não quer enviar a página para o servidor... Deixo um exemplo do código a funcionar com o seu HTML mudando o pedaço que coloquei em cima: http://jsfiddle.net/28nq8mcc/

Comment: Sérgio, valeu pela força... fiquei três dias direto com isso sem solução. Valeu mesmo, funcionou perfeitamente. Abraço.

Comment: @Fabiano se a resposta solucionou o seu problema pode clicar e marcar como aceite.